# How to indent notes in `tabularray`

Tags: tabularray

I use the `tabularray` package to make a table, into which I insert a note, but it shows with insuitable indentation. How to change the indentation of the note to make it align with the colon?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{talltblr}[
        caption={table},
    remark{Hello}={It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.}
        ]{
            colspec={X[c] *{2}{X[c,2]}}
        }
         &HI&HI\\
        low&$<10$&$<0$\\
        me&$20\leq\quad\leq 30$&$40\leq\quad\leq 50$\\
        hogh&$>0$&$>50$\\
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE**: I have added a second example, where only one table uses the indented notes. Also in this example `\linewidth` is used instead of `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\newlength\labellength
\DefTblrTemplate{remark}{default}{%
  \MapTblrRemarks{%
    \settowidth{\labellength}{\UseTblrTemplate{remark-tag}{default}\UseTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{default}}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-tag}{default}\UseTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{default}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\labellength}{\UseTblrTemplate{remark-text}{default}}%
    \par
}}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{talltblr}[
        caption={table},
    remark{Hello}={It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.}
        ]{
            colspec={X[c] *{2}{X[c,2]}}
        }
         &HI&HI\\
        low&$<10$&$<0$\\
        me&$20\leq\quad\leq 30$&$40\leq\quad\leq 50$\\
        hogh&$>0$&$>50$\\
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second example:** Here I use a **theme**, so that you can choose which tables use the solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\newlength\labellength
\DefTblrTemplate{remark}{indentednotes}{%
  \MapTblrRemarks{%
    \settowidth{\labellength}{\UseTblrTemplate{remark-tag}{default}\UseTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{default}}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-tag}{default}\UseTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{default}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\labellength}{\UseTblrTemplate{remark-text}{default}}%
    \par}
}
\NewTblrTheme{indentednotes}{
    \SetTblrTemplate{remark}{indentednotes}
}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{talltblr}[
        theme = indentednotes,
        caption={table with indented notes},
    remark{Hello}={It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.}
        ]{
            colspec={X[c] *{2}{X[c,2]}}
        }
         &HI&HI\\
        low&$<10$&$<0$\\
        me&$20\leq\quad\leq 30$&$40\leq\quad\leq 50$\\
        hogh&$>0$&$>50$\\
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{talltblr}[
        caption={table with normal notes},
    remark{Hello}={It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.It is a very long note.}
        ]{
            colspec={X[c] *{2}{X[c,2]}}
        }
         &HI&HI\\
        low&$<10$&$<0$\\
        me&$20\leq\quad\leq 30$&$40\leq\quad\leq 50$\\
        hogh&$>0$&$>50$\\
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: May you tell me why you know the answer. What should I do to become as good as you about LaTeX?

Comment: Is there a way to modify the indent width in a table not in all tables?

Comment: I think it would be better to replace `\textwidth` with `\linewidth`, which will make the solution work for narrower tables.

Comment: "Is there a way to modify the indent width in a table not in all tables?". Yes, by using a theme. I have added a second example with the theme.

Comment: And why I know the answer? I have been working with LaTeX for more than 30 years. I am curious, and if I don't know something that I need or that I want to know, I read all the necessary documentation, look for answers that others have given and just start experimenting until I get the answer.

Comment: Hello, I found another question: when the table is in `\begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}[-2cm}...\end{adjustwidth}`, the notes width is too narrow. How to make it adjusted with new width?

Comment: Okay. I see that using `theme` can solve this problem, but how to do this without `theme`?